# rm fails to delete files by wildcard from a script, but works from a shell prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've run into a really silly problem with a Linux shell script. I want to delete all files with the extension ".bz2" in a directory. In the script I call

```
rm "$archivedir/*.bz2"
```

where $archivedir is a directory path. Should be pretty simple, shouldn't it? Somehow, it manages to fail with this error:

```
rm: cannot remove `/var/archives/monthly/April/*.bz2': No such file or directory
```

But there *is* a file in that directory called test.bz2 and if I change my script to

```
echo rm "$archivedir/*.bz2"
```

and copy/paste the output of that line into a terminal window the file is removed successfully. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the correct way of doing it if a variable contains the wildcard? Say `archivedir="/var/foo/*.bz2"`.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Quote only the variable, not the whole expected path with the wildcard

```
rm "$archivedir"/*.bz2
```

**Explanation**

- In Unix, programs generally do not interpret wildcards themselves. The shell interprets unquoted wildcards, and replaces each wildcard argument with a list of matching file names.
  if $archivedir might contain spaces, then `rm $archivedir/*.bz2` might not do what you
- You can disable this process by quoting the wildcard character, using double or single quotes, or a backslash before it. However, that's not what you want here - you do want the wildcard expanded to the list of files that it matches.
- Be careful about writing `rm $archivedir/*.bz2` (without quotes). The word splitting (i.e., breaking the command line up into arguments) happens *after* $archivedir is substituted. So if $archivedir contains spaces, then you'll get extra arguments that you weren't intending. Say archivedir is `/var/archives/monthly/April to June`. Then you'll get the equivalent of writing `rm /var/archives/monthly/April to June/*.bz2`, which tries to delete the files "/var/archives/monthly/April", "to", and all files matching "June/*.bz2", which isn't what you want.

The correct solution is to write:

```
rm "$archivedir"/*.bz2
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea the shell does the wildcard operations instead of the actual filesystem programs. This is good to know!

Comment: Interesting explanation , but it does not explain why it works when executed directly at prompt

Comment: Running "sudo rm /var/lib/OnlyRootCanList/*" will not  work when the current user is not allowed to list the files in that directory. In such cases a find command would work better. such as `find . -name "*.jpg" | xargs rm `

Answer (score 12):

Your original line

```
rm "$archivedir/*.bz2"
```

Can be re-written as

```
rm "$archivedir"/*.bz2
```

to achieve the same effect.  The wildcard expansion is not taking place properly in your existing setup.  By shifting the double-quote to the "front" of the file path (which is legitimate) you avoid this.

Answer (score 9):

Just to expand on this a bit, bash has fairly complicated rules for dealing with metacharacters in quotes.  In general

- almost nothing is interpreted in single-quotes:

  ```
   echo '$foo/*.c'                  => $foo/*.c
   echo '\\*'                       => \\*
  ```
- shell substitution is done inside double quotes, but file metacharacters aren't expanded:

  ```
   FOO=hello; echo "$foo/*.c"       => hello/*.c
  ```
- everything inside backquotes is passed to the subshell which interprets them.  A shell variable that is not exported doesn't get defined in the subshell.  So, the first command echoes blank, but the second and third echo "bye":

  ```
  BAR=bye echo `echo $BAR`
  BAR=bye; echo `echo $BAR`
  export BAR=bye; echo `echo $BAR`
  ```

(And getting this to print the way you want it in SO <s>takes several tries</s> is apparently impossible...)

Answer (score 4):

The quotes are causing the string to be interpreted as a string literal, try removing them.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar errors when calling a shell script like 
**./shell_script.sh**
 from another shell script. This can be fixed by invoking it as
**sh shell_script.sh**

Comment: This is just cargo cult programming. There is no reason that the wrong shell would cause this particular error. -1

Answer (score -1):

Why not just `rm -rf */*.bz2`? Works for me on OSX.

Comment: With ZSH it works, with SH it doesn't