# Delete script in Linux

Tags: bash

I am trying to edit the following script to add a part to remove all files within a folder containing the word TRAR in their filename. This is a Linux system, I want to add in a part like this :

```
 cd /appl/virtuo/gways/config/input_d
 rm -rf TRAR*
```

The above I cannot get to run, but when I try manually, I am able to do it, I want to add into the below script and am quite lost, as this is my first time writing such a script

```
VENDOR=ericsson-msc
RELEASE=R13.2
BASE_DIR=/appl/virtuo/gways
RAW_DIR=${BASE_DIR}/config/${VENDOR}/${RELEASE}/trdipfile_raw_landing_area



cd ${RAW_DIR}

ssh netperf@10.76.26.1 "cd /var/opt/ericsson/sgw/outputfiles/apgfiles/oms ; find . -newer ~/msc-         trdif-timestamp -type f | egrep TRDIP | cpio -oc ; touch ~/msc-trdif-timestamp" 2>/dev/null | cpio -icdu 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790195/rm-fails-to-delete-files-by-wildcard-from-a-script-but-works-from-a-shell-promp

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot get it to run"? Is there an error message, or does the computer slide into a ditch?

Comment: I mean I execute it, but nothing happens

Comment: try to cd "$RAW_DIR" as well

Comment: the command now works, but I am not sure where in the script should I add it into, perhaps right at the bottom, as I do not want to interfere with the original function of the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried it both without quotes and with, try quotes and it should work, just tested, also if you want to delete all instances containing "TRAR" you should use wildcard before and after:

```
rm -rf *"TRAR"*
```

you can also try to save it to variable and test:

```
delit="TRAR"
rm -rf "$delit"*
```